# Lapis input validation

Tags: lua

I am having problem while learning Lua/Lapis for the first time here.

**Existing conditions**: When validation fails the controller display a view (I don't know which one). When validation passed the sign-in view is displayed correctly.

**Expected conditions**: I want to render the sign-up view with error message when the input validations failed. When the validation is passed it should redirected to sign-in view.

Here is my controller:

```
app:post("/signup", capture_errors(function(self)
  validate.assert_valid(self.params, {
    { "email", exists = true },
    { "password", exists = true },
    { "confirm_password", equals = self.params.password }
  })

  return { redirect_to = "/signin" }
end))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`capture_errors` provides a default error handler that looks like this:

```
function() return { render = true } end
```

See http://leafo.net/lapis/reference/utilities.html#application-helpers-safe_fn--capture_errorsfn_or_tbl

It says is to render the default view for that action. This is useful when you want to show the errors on the same page as the form.

In order to override the error handler you could write:

```
app:post("/signup", capture_errors({
  on_error = function(self)
    return { redirect_to = "/signin" }
  end,
  function(self)
    validate.assert_valid(self.params, {
      { "email", exists = true },
      { "password", exists = true },
      { "confirm_password", equals = self.params.password }
    })

    return { redirect_to = "/signin" }
  end
}))
```

You can see a full example in the reference manual here: http://leafo.net/lapis/reference/exception_handling.html#capturing-recoverable-errors

I don't recommend doing a redirect on a POST with errors because you won't have access to the error messages. (Which are normally in `self.errors` in the same request)

Comment: Ah finally an answer. Thanks I will try your suggestion